# How to access a Vue inside another Vue?

Tags: c#, html, vue.js, model-view-controller, razor

This are my codes in 2 different `.chtml` files that each includes `.js` file.

- Layout.cshtml
- File1.cshtml
- vue1.js
- vue2.js

I'm using `c#` `.net` `mvc`

---

Layout.cshtml

```html
 <div id="vuemainlayoutdiv">

    <button v-on:click="onClick1()>
    Click 1
    </button>

   <!--rendering File.html-->
   @RenderBody()

</div>
```

File1.cshtml

```html
   <div id="AppcentralVue">

    <button v-on:click="onClick2()>

      Click 1

    </button>

    </div>
```

vue1.js

```js
new Vue({
el: '#vuemainlayoutdiv',
    data: {
        name: 'first click',
    },
   methods: {
        onClick1: function(){
            alert(this.name);
        }
    }
});
```

vue2.js

```js
new Vue({
el: '#AppcentralVue',
    data: {
        name: 'second click',
    },
   methods: {
        onClick2: function(){
            alert(this.name);
        }
    }
});
```

I'm trying to access `Vue` from another `Vue`, but can't reach my target. Therefore I'm asking for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using a state pattern (check vuejs doc [Vue.js State Management Guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html))

Basically, you create a data object and allow your instances to "share" it.
Therefore, you can access and mutate this object from those instances, and it behaves in a reactive way.

If your application grow up, you should evaluate using vuex ([Vuex](http://vuex.vuejs.org/)), which helps you with some issues you may find when working with state management, such as painful debugging.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: how would vuex help my project ?

Comment: Very well explained on the link/guide.